# How to get the last cell separator of a UITableView take the full length?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to have the last cell separator of my UITableView take the full length

[image]

I tried this code but it doesn't change anything:

```
// in UITableViewDelegate 
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell:UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
     cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
     cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}

//UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
     tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero 
}
```

Comment: You are setting _all_ the separators. Do you want _all_ of them to have full length or just the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` property. Let's say your table view has 1 section and 20 rows. Then you would say:

```
if indexPath.row == 19 {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
} else {
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
}
```

You can see that it works:

[image]

Comment: That code is from my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Comment: Obviously you have to adapt the code so that it works for _you_. I don't know the name of your cell variable in _your_ implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do I??? I'm not trying to write your code literally; I'm showing you how it's done. You do still have to do stuff on your own, like thinking.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the trailing space of a button in the last cell? I have a button in the right side of every cell, and when i used your solution , the button in the last cell moved a little bit to the left ( I assume that since the line moved , the button also moved ). So now all the buttons are aligned except the last button in the modified last cell.

Comment: A button has an intrinsic width. So if you don't like where it is, and it needs to be aligned with respect to the right side, delete the leading space constraint that positions it and use a trailing space constraint instead. - But if it didn't already have any constraints, then you will need both a trailing constraint and a top or bottom constraint.

Comment: Here is the example showing the undesired result : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744832/how-to-modify-the-trailing-space-of-a-button-in-the-last-cell-of-a-uitableview