# How to modify the trailing space of a button in the last cell of a UITableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to have the last cell separator of my `UITableView` to take the full length (my table has 20 rows)

I used this code :

```
if indexPath.row == 19 {
   cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
   cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
   cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
} else {
   cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
}
```

I got the desired result, with a little glitch.

Basically, I have a button on the right side of every cell
and when I used the above solution, the button in the last cell moved a little bit to the left (I assume that since the line moved, the button also moved). So now all the buttons are aligned except the last button in the modified last cell.

Question:

Is there a way to modify the trailing space of the button in the last cell?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how that button is positioned? Were you using a trailing constraint already? I think you were, and I think I know what the problem is...

Comment: I'm using a constraint in the xib file of the cell, if I try to modify it the three buttons move ( which is normal )

Comment: Yup, I know how to fix it. Hang on, typing my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal.

You positioned this thing with a constraint. But when you did that, you didn't realize you were positioning it with a constraint *to the margin*, not to the absolute edge of the cell.

But when we changed the margin-related values for that one cell, *we moved the margin*. So the button moved with it.

Solution: go back into the xib file and change that constraint so it is with respect to the edge of the cell, not the margin. Now it won't be affected by the change in the margin, and all the cells will look the same.

Comment: For more detail, and a screen shot, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27976007/341994

Comment: No problem. I got you into this mess so I feel it is my job to get you out of it. :)

Comment: It's great, now i'm sure i won't make this mistake again :)